# undefined local variable or method `form' for Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I'm attempting to show a department view on my product#new page, this is my product#new page

```
<% @produto.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <%= msg %>
</div>   
<% end %>
<%= form_for @produto do |produto| %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= produto.label :nome %>
            <%= produto.text_field :nome, class:"form-control" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= produto.label :descricao %>
            <%= produto.text_area :descricao, class:"form-control", rows:"4" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= form.label :departamento %>
            <%= form.collection_select :departamento_id, @departamentos, :id, :nome, {}, class:"form-control" %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <%= produto.submit "Criar",class:"btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my product_controller.rb

```
class ProdutosController < ApplicationController
def index
    @produtos = Produto.order(nome: :asc).limit 5
    @produtos_com_desconto = Produto.order(:preco).limit 1
end

def new
    @produto = Produto.new
    @departamentos = Departamento.all
end 


def create
    valores_produto = params.require(:produto).permit(:nome, :descricao, :preco, :quantidade)
    @produto = Produto.new valores_produto
    #Produto.create valores_produto
    if @produto.save
        flash[:notice] = "Produto criado com sucesso!"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render :new
    end
end

def destroy
    id = params[:id]
    Produto.destroy id
    redirect_to root_url
end

def search
    @nome = params[:nome]
    @produtos = Produto.where "nome like ?", "%#{@nome}%"
end

end
```

So, when i'm trying to access my product/new page , i'm receiving the error NameError in Produtos#new: undefined local variable or method `form' for #<#<Class.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= form.label :departamento %>` is looking for the `form` variable but there is none defined. Instead `<%= form_for @produto do |produto| %>` has defined `producto` and uses it as `<%= produto.label :nome %>`. So you probably want `<%= producto.label :departamento %>`

Note the variable should probably be `form`. The variable is a [FormBuilder](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html), not a Produto. Calling it `producto` is confusing.